# Laravel 5 updating the view using dropdowns

Tags: php, laravel, select, view, dropdown

I have an resource controller called `AppointmentsController` and a model called `Appointment`. In my model I put a few scopes I use to filter results, like so:

```
public function scopeStatus($query, $statusId)
{
    if($statusId)
    {
        return $query->where('status_id', '=', $statusId);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have this for `month`, `year`, `label`, and a few other settings. I call my query in the controller, like so:

```
$appointments = Appointment::latest('start')->status($statusId)->get();
```

All these variables (`$statusId`, `$labelId`, and so on) are set using dropdowns. Once I select another value in the dropdown, I will be redirected to my view again, with the correct value set and with the correct query.

The thing I'm struggling with how to set the `$statusId` (and other variables). If I use a post request I need to use an extra route (since I am using the store route from the resource route to create appointments). Which would be something like:

```
Route::post('appointments/whatever', 'AppointmentsController@index');
```

Or:

```
Route::post('appointments/whatever', 'AppointmentsController@whatever');
```

So I would fetch the $request values and then update my query accordingly, and then return the view again. Another thing I could do, is store the values in a session (not my preferred way). I could also update the values in the database, then go back to the index method, grab the results from the database and then update my view again.

Any thoughts how I should go about doing this? I can get it to work the amateuristic way but I want to learn how to do this in a proper manner, maybe there is even something I haven't thought of yet or maybe even my code is not good enough. Anything that helps me go in the right direction will answer my question.

Comment: You need to create 2 routes for the `index` method. 1 for the `POST` and 2nd for the `Get` so If the request is get show whatever otherwise get the `requested` search and load it to your view.

Comment: I think I finally found "the best way" (read: the best way for me personally) after posting this question. I am using a `PostController` and using a post route that calls `PostController@appointment` that sets the values in the database and redirects to the `AppointmentsController@index`. Cleanest way, I think :)